# Facebook Ad Keyword Stats is not woking

Tags: facebook

I wang to get the ad keyword stats using Facebook API, the reference API docs is :

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-keyword-stats/

I used https://graph.facebook.com/v11/ad_id/keywordstats?access_token=alskfajslkfjdlasjfldjaslkfdjlaksjlfkslfkdlasfd

ad_id used: AD ID

alskfajslkfjdlasjfldjaslkfdjlaksjlfkslfkdlasfd using real token.

but I got an error:

**{
"error": {
"message": "(#12) Ads keywords stats is deprecated for versions v5.0 and higher",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 12,
"fbtrace_id": "AUGEDqfoo-5VroAam7bYIWf"
}
}**

if I use v5.0, it will get :

**{
"error": {
"message": "(#2635) You are calling a deprecated version of the Ads API. Please update to the latest version: v11.0.",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 2635,
"fbtrace_id": "Ayp8vk9LmHaSb5hKWFFnY_B"
}
}**

so what should I do ?